# Matching PowerShell reference assemblies with .NET framework versions

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, nuget, powershell-cmdlet

Until today the [blue pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_pill_and_blue_pill) kept me happily ignoring an interesting point. But a very recent [post by James Truher](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/12/12/powershell-sdk-reference-assemblies-available-via-nuget-org.aspx) (Microsoft's PowerShell Team), swapped it out for the red pill. And that led to this train of thought...

Before last week, writing cmdlets in C# involved digging up a copy of `System.Management.Automation.dll` from wherever one could find it (or, if satisfied with PowerShell v3 specifically, then from the V3 reference assemblies installed by VS2013 in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0`. Either way, it was not nearly as robust a way to maintain a connection to that DLL as provided by nuget.

But now, as Truher announced, the PowerShell reference assemblies *are* available through nuget--*hooray!* Except Microsoft has provided reference assemblies not just for V3, but for PowerShell V3, V4, and V5.

What I am wondering is: are there constraints as to which version of PowerShell reference assemblies versus which version of the .NET framework one should use together? Or is it simply that, if the system on which I want to run my custom C# cmdlets has PowerShell version **x** installed, then I just use reference assemblies version **x** in development?

And one more point I need clarification on in a slightly broader context: currently I have a solution that references `System.Management.Automation.dll` from the GAC, and `CopyLocal` is set false, so it then uses the DLL in the GAC at runtime. Wouldn't that be preferred rather than having a private copy of the reference assembly downloaded from nuget and kept in my solution?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by last paragraph. Reference assemblies can not be used at runtime, because them does not have code. Reference assemblies contains set of public types and members that you can use in particular version of PowerShell, so that you accidently not use v4 member if you targeting for v3. In runtime you will use assembly from GAC anyway.